# IE9 rendering css3

Tags: css

Hi recently I have started to develop a website which uses a few basic css3 features which I am sure that are supported in IE9 because I've checked. No matter what I did IE9 seemed not to render any of the css3 properties not even when I was using *ms* prefix.

After I did some reasearch I found a question here on stackoverflow that dealt with a similar problem to mine and someone offered a solution to that problem.The person said to add this line in the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

After I added this everything seemed to work. What I would is an explanation as to why do I have to use this to make css3 features work in IE9 and what is it's meaning?

I am still prety new to web development and I tried to learn html/css/javasript/php/mysql in about 6 months. While I am now capable of creating functional websites alot of gaps seem to be left in my head so I hope this is not a very basic question.

Comment: It's not your fault - it's Microsoft's...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the document compatibility.

It's all explained in this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Essentially it's MS being difficult again.

Comment: AFAIK using the HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>` should also solve those problems.

Comment: Or pretty much any doctype that triggers standards mode.